# How to scrape data with special characters?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm using python framework scrapy to scrape data, here is code for my spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//h1')
    links = hxs.select('//div[@class="pp-title"]')
    #sites = hxs.select('//div[@id="yt-lockup-content"] ')

    items = []
    for site in links:
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('a/h1/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()

        items.append(item)

    return items
```

I collect data in `items.json` with this spider, I run spider with command `scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.json -t json`. Data are stored in format

```
[[{"link": ["http://www.ponudadana.hr/Planinarski-dom-Kalnik-2-dana-s-doruckom-za-dvoje-za-149kn-umjesto-300kn-7482_1"], "title": ["Planinarski dom Kalnik - 2 dana s doru\u010dkom za dvoje za 149kn umjesto 300kn!"]},
```

The problem is that special characters like `č,ž,š,đ,ž` are stored as `\u010` or similar, for example see the word above `doru\u010dkom`, it should be `doručkom`. Can anyone help me, should I use some encoding format?

Comment: could you fix the indentation error on the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it's JSON or Python unicode string literals, `\u010d` **means** `č`. Even if it's represented like that in JSON, when you decode it, it will come out as a proper letter `č`.

```
>>> import json
>>> obj = json.loads("""{"link": ["http://www.ponudadana.hr/Planinarski-dom-Kalnik-2-dana-s-doruckom-za-dvoje-za-149kn-umjesto-300kn-7482_1"], "title": ["Planinarski dom Kalnik - 2 dana s doru\u010dkom za dvoje za 149kn umjesto 300kn!"]}""")
>>> obj['title']
[u'Planinarski dom Kalnik - 2 dana s doru\u010dkom za dvoje za 149kn umjesto 300kn!']
>>> print obj['title'][0]
Planinarski dom Kalnik - 2 dana s doručkom za dvoje za 149kn umjesto 300kn!
```

Same aplies for Python strings.

```
>>> u"česnakas"
u'\u010desnakas'
>>> print u"česnakas"
česnakas
```

Comment: I tried but get this error   File "mongodb.py", line 25, in <m
    print title
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\c
    return codecs.charmap_encode(in
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec
 38: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: here is my code for printing : json_data=open('items.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

for d in data:
    link=d['link'][0]
    link=link.strip()
    title=d['title'][0]
    title=title.strip()
    
    print title
    print link

Comment: AFAIK 'charmap' indicates a problem with Windows CMD that doesn't really handle unicode well.

Comment: thx, it was problem with cmd , I run script with idle python , and print workos normally , thx :)